# Install4j - Creating OSX Java 7 JRE bundle

Tags: bundle, java, install4j

I am trying to create a JRE bundle for OSX using install4j's createbundle utility.  Unfortunately the utility is not included in the OSX installation.

I tried using the ant task described in the following document:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/jreBundle.html

but it complains that createbundle does not exist.

What is the recommended way of creating a JRE bundle for OSX Java 7?  Is there a version of create bundle available for OSX?  I am looking for a bundle of the latest JRE (Java7u10).

Answer (score 0):

Creating new JRE bundles on Mac OS X is not yet supported (as of 5.1.3), it will be added in a future version. 7u10 bundles will be added later today.